# What does the new() constraint do on a class definition?

Tags: c#, oop, class, inheritance, polymorphism

I saw this code example and was wondering what the purpose of the `new()` constraint was:

```
public class Client<T> : IClient where T : IClientFactory, new()
{
    public Client(int UserID){ }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's called a "'new' constraint".  [Here's the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on it.

> The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class declaration must have a **public parameterless constructor**. To use the new constraint, the type cannot be abstract.

(Emphasis mine)

Basically, you need it whenever you're creating a new `T` somewhere in the class, to ensure that you're only able to pass in things which the compiler *can* create a new instance of.

Answer (score 2):

`Client` is a collection of `T` objects, and those `T` objects must implement the `IClientFactory` interface and have a public parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 2):

new() means

> The type argument must have a public parameterless constructor. When
>   used together with other constraints, the new() constraint must be
>   specified last.

Ref [Generic Constraints on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)